# Use Process.Start to open explorer.exe window to UNC path that requires login

Tags: c#, .net, unc, windows-explorer, process.start

I would like to open a Windows Explorer window to a UNC path that requires a login outside of my network using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. I do not want or need to pass credentials to actually access the folder, I just want to open an explorer window to that path and have it pop up its own login prompt for the user. When I try, it opens to the user's Documents folder on the local machine instead, and no exceptions are thrown. When I run it within the domain where the UNC folder is located, it opens the proper path. I can access the path within explorer manually from outside the domain (after the login prompt).

I'm calling this from a thread, so I'm using Invoke.

```
public void OpenExplorer(string path)
{
    //string path = string.Format("\"{0}\"", path); // tried wrapping path in quotes
    
    var openExplorer = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "explorer.exe",
        Arguments = "/open " + path,
        // Arguments = "/open, " + path,    // tried with and without comma
        // Arguments = path,                // tried without /open
        UseShellExecute = true              // tried with and without UseShellExecute
    };

    this.Invoke(new Action(() => { System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openExplorer); }));
}
```

How can I get explorer to open the correct path and prompt with a login as it does when you enter the path manually?

Comment: *When I run it within the network* -- what does this sentense mean exactly?

Comment: Within the network = at work, signed in to domain. Outside the network = running it from home, signed into local machine. I'll try to edit.

Comment: can you try `net use` command?

Comment: @LeiYang `net use` is not really relevant to my problem.

Comment: there's still something else to try(as you show already tried 3 things), FileName  = `cmd.exe`, maybe followed by `/c  ...`

Comment: From what little is [documented](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html), Explorer doesn't seem to support an `/open` argument and it's not clear why you think it does. `explorer <path>` does work, provided the path is valid; if not Explorer will indeed just open the Documents folder (it will never produce an error). From my brief tests it appears to be a requirement that the server name resolves, but no more than that; that is, `Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"\\myserver\mypath")` just works and prompts if necessary, provided `myserver` is reachable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I found the /open argument here on stackoverflow, and it's just one of the things I tried which you can see from the code comments. Try the one with the comma from the cmd prompt or run dialog - it works, just not from within my program. If `Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"\\myserver\mypath")` "just worked" I wouldn't need to ask the question because that's the first thing I tried. The path is reachable.

Comment: I make it a point never to assume anything I don't need to assume; your original question doesn't mention the form I tested, so I wouldn't know that was the first thing you tried. For what it's worth: that specific form works for me, in my setup with a UNC path, prompting for credentials, so at the very least this confirms *that* specific invocation works in *some* circumstances.

Comment: In the "you never know" category, see if the bitness of your program matters (that is, make it 64-bit if running on a 64-bit OS). FWIW my test was conducted on a machine running W10 21H1, though I can't really see that mattering either. Also see (somehow) if the `Invoke` is the problem (you say you're calling it "from a thread" -- did you mean "from a control"?) by just trying the call directly from `Main`. Whatever the ultimate cause of the difference, it's probably not the argument list.